# How to break with GDB at object destruction if there is no destructor?

Tags: c++, gdb, destructor

How to break with GDB at object destruction if there is no destructor?

Comment: What's the purpose of watching behaviour of nonwritten code?

Comment: For example verifying memory leak that was noticed using other tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's no destructor, you cannot break on the destructor, as there is no op-code for the destructor. You have two choices on where to break:

- If the object is allocated on the stack, break on the closing brace of the scope defining the variable.
- If the object is allocated on the heap, break on the delete statement.
- If the object is statically allocated in a data segment, then you can't.

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22847303) question you can, I'll test it now.