# Can gdb break on implicit class methods?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, destructor, copy-constructor

The compiler generates some class methods like copy constructors, destructors, etc. Is it possible to have gdb break on those methods to, e.g., observe where objects are being copied or destroyed?

Comment: You can break on the constructors / destructors of the types of the members

Comment: Often, and in the case I'm looking at now, all the members also have implicitly defined {copy,move} constructors/destructors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can gdb break on implicit class methods?

Yes, of course, it can.

```
(gdb) break MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass &)     // break when copied
(gdb) break MyClass::~MyClass()                   // break when object destroyed
```

as simple as that. These are breakpoints based, NOT on file:line, but on function names. If you've a namespace wrapping the class then  make sure you give the fully qualified name for it e.g.

```
(gdb) break NyNamespace::MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass &)
```

Look [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Specify-Location.html#Specify-Location) for a list of ways to specify breakpoints in GDB.

Comment: Using gdb 7.5.1 and gcc 4.7.2 and compiling with -ggdb, I find that setting the breakpoints on the implicit methods sets a breakpoint on the line that defines the class. Interestingly, if I set a breakpoint at that file:lieno, gdb asks me which breakpoint I want to set, giving me a choice of all the implicitly defined methods!

Comment: odd that it doesn't work for me. gdb did set a breakpoint (at 3 locations?) when I asked it to break at boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::task_io_service().  Then, when I ran the program on top of gdb, I got errors like these "Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Error accessing memory address 0x11: Input/output error."

Comment: well, can this works on a template specialist class?

Comment: @cli__ I tried [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b46d1bca0a295715) program locally with GCC 8.2.1 and GDB 8.2. It works. I gave `b area<int>` and `r`. It broke inside `area`, doing a `bt` showed that the first `float` variant call in `main` was skipped and it only broke into the `int` variant.

Comment: For me it always fails here with `Function "MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass&)" not defined.` etc. I created a minimal main file, and also added a simple `void ok() {}` method to `MyClass`. Adding a breakpoint for `ok` works fine (via `break MyClass::ok()`). This is true even with all flags I can think of: `-g -ggdb -O0`.

Answer (score 1):

gdb can break on anything that is either mentioned in the debuginfo or as an ELF sybmol.  Offhand I do not know whether your compiler emits debuginfo for these artificial methods.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar needs, I built my code with

```
g++ main.cpp -std=c++1y -o app_name -g -ggdb
```

but gdb can't see my implict constructors and assignment operators symbols. And for this reason it don't break on them. 
Because of that I've used this hack to be able to break on implicitly defined methods of examined class: just implement your own class with explicitly defined methods you're interesting in. Then add this new class object as data member of class you want to debug. Set breakpoints on methods of new class. Enjoy!

Example:

```
class LifeCycleInspector
{
public:
    LifeCycleInspector()
    {
        printf( "Default C-tor\n" );
    }

    LifeCycleInspector( const LifeCycleInspector& )
    {
        printf( "Copy C-tor\n" );
    }

    LifeCycleInspector( LifeCycleInspector&& )
    {
        printf( "Move C-tor\n" );
    }

    LifeCycleInspector& operator=( const LifeCycleInspector& )
    {
        printf( "Copy A-ment\n" );
        return *this;
    }

    LifeCycleInspector& operator=( LifeCycleInspector&& )
    {
        printf( "Move A-ment\n" );
        return *this;
    }

    virtual ~LifeCycleInspector()
    {
        printf( "D-tor\n" );
    }
};

class Test
{
private:
    LifeCycleInspector lci_;
};

void foo()
{
    Test t1;
    Test t2( t1 );
    Test t3;
    t3 = t1;
    Test t4( std::move( t3 ) );
    Test t5;
    t5 = std::move( t4 );
}

int main()
{
    foo();

    return 0;
}
```

Output sample:

```
Default C-tor
Copy C-tor
Default C-tor
Copy A-ment
Move C-tor
Default C-tor
Move A-ment
D-tor
D-tor
D-tor
D-tor
D-tor
```

**Important!** If you make your methods empty, like:

```
LifeCycleInspector( const LifeCycleInspector& )
{   
}
```

- your compiler optimization may do fancy things and your debug output may be pretty strange. In this case you may add some routine to the methods to prevent optimization. Also you should move methods implementation from class to its header or source, as defining method right in class's body is implicitly making this method an candidate for inlining. gdb will not break on inlined methods because they usually have no definition which could be adressed.

Comment: "it is better to move methods implementation from header to source."  Whether that is true is *highly* contextual.  Also, adding a member adds memory overhead to the class it is added to, even if the object is empty, so while it's useful for debugging purposes, it could be very expensive if there are a very large number of objects of that type.   Inheriting from it instead will allow for empty bass class optimizations.

Comment: thanks, what I meant, is that you should avoid to defining methods in class's body as this implicitly makes them candidates for inlining (same when you're using MyClass::MyClass() = default; definition outside you class's body - even if you've moved it to source file). and, unless you take an address of it, inlined method has no actual head/body, gdb can't break on it. it worth mentioning that EBO isn't working for multiple inheritance and that class with no data memory's footprint is usually like 1 char.

Comment: What do you mean EBO "isn't working" for MI?  https://godbolt.org/g/JHe1Gn  Looks fine to me.

Comment: It must be 'EBO is generally not working for MI'. Source 'Effective C++ 3rd edition' : Item39’s observation that the EBO generally isn’t available under multiple inheritance is  from  David  Vandevoorde’s  and  Nicolai  M.  Josuttis’ C++  Templates (Addison-Wesley,  2003).

Comment: Well, then it's good to know we've made some progress in 15 years.