# How to set a breakpoint at implicitly defined, declared constructor?

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, g++

Is there a way to set a breakpoint at implicitly defined, declared constructor?

I would like to know whether the implicitly defined constructor in a header only 3rd party library is called.  (Of course, one option is to explicitly declare and define it and then set a breakpoint there; but I have no such permission on that machine)

Thanks in advance.

Update

(gdb) break boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::task_io_service()
Breakpoint 1 at 0x11: file /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/task_io_service.ipp, line 75. (3 locations)
(gdb) run
................
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Error accessing memory address 0x11: Input/output error.
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Error accessing memory address 0xb7: Input/output error.

Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.80.el6_3.7.x86_64

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/22869484/2724703

Comment: Did you try first putting the break point on main and run the program.

Comment: The problem is that boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::task_io_service is created by another 3rd party library and so I was hoping to set a breakpoint right at boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::task_io_service's implicit constructor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can gdb break on implicit class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22847303/can-gdb-break-on-implicit-class-methods)